# How to make difference between received Authentication and LogOut SAML response

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

How to make distinction between AuthetnicationResponse and LogOutResponse SAML messages?

I do not see any specific flag within SAMLP tags.

In both cases I got message that starts like  and that is all.

Comment: AuthenticationResponse will have <saml:Assertion> inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my traces with ADFS, AuthnResponse starts:

```
<samlp:Response ID="_8e126050-b9d2-4da6-9b25-1e9eb02eb61b"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2012-11-08T00:55:26.375Z"
```

whereas LogoutResponse starts:

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse ID="_37f28ec7-1420-4f15-b7d3-ec8c62a156ab"
                      Version="2.0"
                      IssueInstant="2012-11-08T00:58:28.348Z"
```